# Can't push: Remote: Your credentials lack one or more required privilege scopes

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, bitbucket

From my main computer (using VS Code), can't push to a remote repository on bitbucket on this one account, but I can clone and pull. I can push to my Github account normally. I have tried this using both command line commands and the GUI.

I have Write access:

[![screenshot of my access level][1]][1]

```
PS C:\xampp\htdocs\REDACTED-tests> git remote -v
origin  https://MichaelWCho@bitbucket.org/REDACTED.git (fetch)       
origin  https://MichaelWCho@bitbucket.org/REDACTED.git (push)
```

```
> git push -u origin test_branch
remote: Your credentials lack one or more required privilege scopes.
fatal: unable to access 'https://bitbucket.org/REDACTED': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

I also work within a VirtualBox, where I have VS Code installed. From here, I can push and do all operations normally. The issue is isolated to my main computer.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCr6B.jpg

Answer (score 5):

I found a solution here: https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Relationship-of-the-git-credentials-and-the-App-key/qaq-p/1136104

The issue seemed to be "interference with the Windows credential store."

- I deleted the bitbucket-related credentials (located in Control Panel > User Accounts > Credential Manager > Generic Credentials).
- Then, when I tried to push, an Atlassian window popped up and prompted me for my password. I entered that.
- Then, it pushed correctly.

In addition to the push, I then deleted a local branch and cloned a repository and all worked without any problems.

Comment: I use source-tree.  So had to remove all the bitbucket and sourcetree related credentials. Then used the terminal to push again and was prompted to authenticate again. Then used o-auth option because it is available with bitbucket.

Answer (score 1):

This simply means that you have no required privilege to perform the particular action.

Please provide the required permissions while creating the **Bitbucket App password** and then try again.
[image]